# Send 1000 emails in a bulk and test the speed

Tags: python, email, smtp

I want to build a script in Python that will send an email to between 2000 and 3000 people. The code looks like this so far:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

#Send email
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
server.starttls()
server.login("myemail","password")
msg = MIMEText("""body""")
sender = 'myemail'
recipients = ['testemail1', 'testemail2']*100
msg['Subject'] = "Subject example"
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)
msg['Body'] = 'this is the body of the email'
server.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
```

The expected result was to receive 100 emails in `testemail1` and 100 in `testemail2`. The actual result was that I received only 1 email in each.

What I'm trying to do is see how long will it take to send that many emails - it's important that the recipients get it in about the same time.

So, the question is: How can I send to myself in 2 personal email boxes the same email 100 times( and rule out `for i in range (1,100):sendmail` because I've already tried it and it takes 1 second/email-which is slow. And is there any service or domain or an email list that I can send this emails to so I can see the send speed?

Comment: You are really trting to do a mass mail speed benchmark on Gmail? Google will love you for that ... and they will block you.

Comment: @KlausD. i only have access to this email now but i'll be trying them on a private email server. Right now i need to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

SMTP servers (usually) ignore duplicated recipients in message (e.g. duplicated `RCPT TO:`) .
They deliver single copy to repeated recipient of message.

If you want to get blocked by gmail then execute `server.sendmail` 1_000 times.